# how to display the query records in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi in the below it's returns the SUCCESSFUL message but I am not getting the id,groupnames.
How to execute the select query in the below code.I wan the record details of id and groupname.

Can any one help me

**php**

```
case "DispalyGroupDetails":
        $userId = authenticateUser($db, $username, $password);

        if ($userId != NULL)

        {

            if (isset($_REQUEST['username']))           
            {               
                 $username = $_REQUEST['username'];



                 $sql = "select Id from users where username='$username' limit 1";

                 if ($result = $db->query($sql))

                 {
                        if ($row = $db->fetchObject($result))

                        {    

                                     $sql = "select g.id,g.groupname from `users` u, `friends` f,`group` g 
                                     where u.Id=f.providerId and f.providerId=g.providerId";
                                    echo $sql;


                                     if ($db->query($sql))
                                     {
                                        $out = SUCCESSFUL;
                                     }
                                     else
                                     {
                                            $out = FAILED;
                                     }

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $out = FAILED;                      
                        }
                 }

                 else
                 {
                        $out = FAILED;
                 }              
            }

            else
            {
                    $out = FAILED;
            }           
        }
        else
        {
            $out = FAILED;
        }   
    break;
```

Comment: there is no need of that much if condition , you can check multiple condition in single if using `&&` or `||` , etc

Comment: $sql = "select g.id,g.groupname from `users` u, `friends` f,`group` g 
          where u.Id=f.providerId and f.providerId=g.providerId"; json format how to execute the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this. You need to fetch the contents of the query as opposed to just getting whether the query was successful.

```
$sql = "select g.id,g.groupname from `users` u, `friends` f,`group` g 
                                 where u.Id=f.providerId and f.providerId=g.providerId";

echo $sql;

$theResult = $db->query($sql);

if ($theResult) {
  $theRow = $db->fetchObject($theResult);
  echo $theRow->id;
  echo $theRow->groupname;
  //Etc 
  $out = SUCCESSFUL;
} else {
     $out = FAILED;
}
```

Comment: how to get the array of id's and groupnames how to write that one

Comment: while(  $theRow = $db->fetchObject($theResult))                                                     {
  echo $theRow->id;
  echo $theRow->groupname;                                                                                       }